# Help with reading and programming 93c56 EEPROM

Tags: eeprom, programmer

I need some advice on software and hardware. I would like to read and program the 93c56 EEPROM chip. The chip is removed from the device. I would like to read the content of the EEPROM and compare it to none corrupt content. Ideally would prefer to purchase a reasonably priced programmer as I do not plan to use it on anything else so I prefer not to spend loads on the hardware. If someone could please point me in the right direction.

[image]

```
#include <M93Cx6.h>

#define PWR_PIN   7
#define CS_PIN    10
#define SK_PIN    13
#define DO_PIN    12
#define DI_PIN    11
#define ORG_PIN   8
#define ORG       16
#define CHIP      56

M93Cx6 eeprom = M93Cx6(PWR_PIN, CS_PIN, SK_PIN, DO_PIN, DI_PIN, ORG_PIN);

void setup() {

  int i = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  //  read string from eeprom
  for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    uint16_t r = eeprom.read(i);  // for ORG_16
    Serial.print(r);
    Serial.print('\n');
    
  }
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products ("a reasonably priced programmer") are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to buy any hardware. Maybe you can use something you already have.

Comment: If you have the time and ability, you could make an Arduino (or clone) read out the contents of the EEPROM. You would need the *Microwire* library and perhaps a small breadboard.

Comment: @StarCat I will try the Microwire approach using Arduino. So it happens that I have all I need small breadboard as well as an arduino nano clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 93C56 is an SPI serial EEPROM. You can use an Arduino Nano clone and the [M93Cx6 library](https://github.com/TauSolutions/M93Cx6). No extra hardware required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was not aware that this chip uses SPI. I am very happy to find out that aurdino has a library for programming this chip. Luckily enough I have a nano clone that I purchased ages ago but never used it (picture attached in the original post). Will try this approach over the weekend and report the results.

Comment: Could you explain how to add 93Cx6 to my library? I have very limited knowledge of arduino. Previously all libraries I used were available in the library manager.

Comment: If you google install arduino library from github, literally the first hit is a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: Apologies for this very basic question I think I run into trouble as the location of the library was incorrect and the name of the library included undesirable signs. As you pointed out google suggested a better source of information than one I used previously.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I assembled the circuit and programed the Arduino. I used the code attached to the original question to obtain the content of the memory. Since I have not done any coding in years and the results printed by the serial monitor appear questionable, I want to seek advice. My goal is to read 128 addresses in the memory. Once I run the program I got “65535” printed about 128 times. This would correlate to hex “FFFF” which is puzzling as it is a content of ECU settings. I suspect that my code is incorrect however there is also a strong possibility of damaged EEPROM.

Comment: FFFF is also what you get if the SPI MISO line is idle at logic-high. Have you checked SCLK, MOSI and CS# with a scope to see if the Arduino is properly driving those signals within the timing specs given in the EEPROM datasheet?

Comment: Not yet I will have access to scope this week and I will investigate. I also tried one of the cheap CH341A programs. They do not have a microwire board interface but there is a way around it by rewiring the pinout. The result was the same 256 cells containing "FF". My code assumes 2byte word organisation rather than one byte still this should not affect the result, should it?